# Browser back-button does't work correctly after window.location.href was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Before my application was written in jQuery and wasn't SPA. I have rewritten some of the pages to AngularJS and made them SPA.

Now I need to have proper comunication beetwen these apps. **Because when I go from Angular page to Angular page, I don't want to reload the page, but when I go to jQuery page, I do want to reload the page so server could send me other source files.**
So, when the link goes to the Angular page (from Angular page), it's simple:

```
<a href="store/categories">
```

And `ui-router` catches `"store/categories"`, changes the state and it doesn't reload the page.

However if the link goes to jQuery page (from Angular page), I can't just specify `<a href="store/categories">`, because `ui-router` will catch it and the page won't reload.

Then I decided to use `window.location.href` to force page reload:

```
<a href="store/categories" ng-click="$root.newHref('store/categories')">

$rootScope.newHref = function(url) {
   var url = ROOT_URL + urlBody; // ROOT_URL is just a protocol with host name
   window.location.href = url;
};
```

And it worked! When you now click on the link it will reload the page with the correct URL.

However if you go to a page using `window.location.href` and then click the **browser back button**, the **URL will change** but the **page won't reload**.

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 2):

Use `target="_self"` instead of `window.location.href`.

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm and is much more simple than fighting with ui-router catching!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem going back and forward between 2 apps.

As the old app didn't use HTML5 History API functionality, i fixed this by added this piece of javascript in the old website pages (in a JavaScript file that was loaded by all pages in the old website:

```
//This will fix a bug with browsers history back API after a window.location from within our Angular apps.
(function () {
  var locationOnPageload = location.href;
  window.onpopstate = function (event) {
    if (location.href !== locationOnPageload) {
      document.location.reload();
    }
  }
})();
```

As Safari on mobile was triggering "onpopstate" on page load, I added the check if href on page-load is different then location onpopstate.

This way I don't have to add target="_self" to all links that go back to our old style pages.